# Show / Hide a particular field based on custom button click in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, togglebutton

I have a Django model like this:

```py
class Webhook(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    credentials = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict)

@admin.register(models.Webhook)
class WebhookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "uuid", "url")
    fields = ("uuid", "url", "toggle_credentials_button", "credentials")
    readonly_fields = ("uuid", "toggle_credentials_button")

    def toggle_credentials_button(self, obj):
        return format_html("""<a class="button">Toggle Credentials</a>&nbsp""")

    toggle_credentials_button.allow_tags = True
```

[image: Django Model Change Page Screenshot]

The `Toggle Credentials` button shown in the screenshot is a custom button. I want to show/hide **credentials** field based on the click/toggle of the `Toggle Credentials` button, i.e. if the **credentials** field is currently being shown, then hide the field after the button is clicked and vice-versa.

By default, the **credentials** field should always be hidden whenever a user visits the page shown in the screenshot, i.e. the showing of the **credentials** field shouldn't persist. If the user clicked the `Toggle Credentials` button to show the **credentials** field, then goes back to some other pages and again comes to this same page, then he should have to again click the button to view the **credentials** field.

Also please note that I won't be using this in any UI or Frontend, so I need the functionality to work in Django Admin only.

**How can I achieve this requirement ?**
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

*Also I am not much versed in Django, so if anyone finds any mistake in my code, please let me know.*